# native c++ extension for Node.js : "cloning" a Local< Value > in the constructor

Tags: c++, node.js, parameter-passing, native

I've read the tutorial "Writing Node.js Native Extensions": https://www.cloudkick.com/blog/2010/aug/23/writing-nodejs-native-extensions

The code worked fine ( https://github.com/pquerna/node-extension-examples/blob/master/helloworld/helloworld.cc )

Now I want to change:

```
class HelloWorld: ObjectWrap
{
private:
  int m_count;
public:
(...)
 HelloWorld() :
    m_count(0)
  {
  }
(...)
 static Handle<Value> Hello(const Arguments& args)
  {
    HandleScope scope;
    HelloWorld* hw = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<HelloWorld>(args.This());
    hw->m_count++;
    Local<String> result = String::New("Hello World");
    return scope.Close(result);
  }
(...)
}
```

to something like that ( copy a parameter in the constructor and return it in 'Hello()' ):

```
class HelloWorld: ObjectWrap
{
private:
  Local< Value > myval;/* <===================== */
public:
(...)
 HelloWorld(const Local< Value >& v) :
   myval(v) /* <===================== */
  {
  }
(...)
 static Handle<Value> Hello(const Arguments& args)
  {
    HandleScope scope;
    HelloWorld* hw = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<HelloWorld>(args.This());
    return scope.Close(hw->myval);/* <===================== */
  }
(...)
}
```

my  code doesn't seem to work, hello() seems to return an integer

```
var h=require("helloworld");
var H=new h.HelloWorld("test");
console.log(H.hello());
```

What's the right way to copy myval in the constructor and return myval in the function 'Hello()' ? And should I manage something in the destructor ?

Thanks.

Pierre

Comment: Have you tried using `args.This()` in the constructor? It's been a while since I tinkered with V8 C++ extensions, but it occurs to me as that you're not setting the myval on the actual instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Local' variables will be automatically cleaned up, so you can't just save a copy of them like that. You need to use a 'Persistent' Handle.

```
class HelloWorld: ObjectWrap
{
private:
  Persistent< Value > myval;
public:
(...)
  HelloWorld(const Local< Value >& v) : 
    myval(Persistent< Value >::New(v)) {

  }
(...)
 static Handle<Value> Hello(const Arguments& args)
  {
    HandleScope scope;
    HelloWorld* hw = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<HelloWorld>(args.This());
    return scope.Close(hw->myval);
  }
(...)
}
```